# How to get unique rows from sql query

Tags: sql, distinct, rows

I want to display the unique records from the query, here is what i write

```
 select DISTINCT Company.FounderId, Shares.PurchasePrice as Share_PurchasedPrice, Company.Name as Company_Name from Company 
    inner join Investment on Investment.CompanyId=Company.FounderId 
    inner join Shares on Shares.Id=Investment.ShareId 
    inner join Founder on Founder.Id=Company.FounderId 
    where Company.FounderId=1
```

and here is its output

[image]

In above query i'm display company name and its shares price according to founderId, but it repeats the values. I want something like this

```
FoundId       Share_PurchasedPrice          Company_Name
1             1323                          Cloudrevel
1             4520                          Dwellsmith
1             30000                         Cloudrevel
```

**update:**

I tried to use group by like this, but it prints same result

```
select  Company.FounderId, Shares.PurchasePrice as Share_PurchasedPrice, Company.Name as Company_Name from Company 
    inner join Investment on Investment.CompanyId=Company.FounderId 
    inner join Shares on Shares.Id=Investment.ShareId 
    inner join Founder on Founder.Id=Company.FounderId 
    where Company.FounderId=1 GROUP BY FounderId,PurchasePrice,Company.Name
```

i tried this way too

```
select  Company.FounderId, Shares.PurchasePrice as Share_PurchasedPrice, Company.Name as Company_Name from Company 
    inner join Investment on Investment.CompanyId=Company.FounderId 
    inner join Shares on Shares.Id=Investment.ShareId 
    inner join Founder on Founder.Id=Company.FounderId 
      GROUP BY Company.FounderId,Shares.PurchasePrice,Company.Name
       HAVING Company.FounderId=1
```

Please help how to get this.

Comment: They are "distinct", so i think you will need to group them

Comment: @Nathan_Sav how to do it?

Comment: Seeing as you gave it 30 seconds, try this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @Nathan_Sav please check my updated query i posted, i tried to use group by but it prints same result

Comment: What about FounderId? IS repeated anyway. I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: And How do you know wich record get for a false "duplicated" if values are different? Or you don't care that value?

Comment: Looking at it, your issue appears to be somewhere else... Maybe one of your joins is not  correct? You are already using distinct, but since you have multiple Company_Names for each result, they can't be grouped more.

Comment: If a distinct FoundId/Share_PurchasedPrice has several (different) Company_Names - which one do you want?

Comment: This looks wrong - `inner join Investment on Investment.CompanyId=Company.FounderId ` .  Since (at least in your sample data) all founderIDs appear to be '1', that incorrect join would lead to your "repeating" results.

Comment: @JenR thank you so much, this join u pointed had problem, i resolved it, thanks once again.